# Access inner html tag

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I got same front end works to do where I need to apply bootstrap. Unfortunately, I'm not much a front end developer :P. Anyway, here I face a problem which is described bellow:

My html:

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">


        <div class="col-xm-12 visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
            <a href="~/TechRoom/Information?eventName=Glassware">
                <p class=" CompetencyUserStory" style="height:222px; width:110%;">
                    <img src="~/Images/TechRoom/google-glass.jpg" style="height:222px; width: 107.6%; margin-left:-15px;" />
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <a href="~/TechRoom/Information?eventName=Glassware">
                <p class=" CompetencyUserStory">
                    <img src="/Images/TechRoom/google-glass.jpg" style="height:304px; width: 104.3%; margin-left:-15px;" />
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 visible-sm hidden-md hidden-xs">
            <a href="~/TechRoom/Information?eventName=Glassware">
                <p class=" CompetencyUserStory">
                    <img src="/Images/TechRoom/google-glass.jpg" style="height:304px; width: 104.4%; margin-left:-15px;" />
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.CompetencyUserStory {
    background: rgba(7, 6, 6, 0.0980392);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 90%;
    height: 304px;
}
```

Here I have used the same HTML thrice just for the sake of setting the image size in different screen size. And I have also used inline css.

1. Now what I actually want to improve here is to get ride of  such inline css(without putting those inline css into extra classes) and by not writing the same html thrice for different screen size just for the sake of an image. Please provide me some help to make the improvement.
2. how can I access the `img` tag to apply different css, say for example

`.col-sm-6 col-md-4 hidden-xs > a > p > img {height:304px; width:100%;}` which does not work.

Comment: take a look at [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Have you tried converting your inline commands to stylesheet declarations?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. But just missed the img element in css.

Use "`.CompetencyUserStory img`" instead of "`.CompetencyUserStory`"

Try below code.

```
.CompetencyUserStory img {
    background: rgba(7, 6, 6, 0.0980392);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 90%;
    height: 304px;
}
```